# Static class vs. static variables best practice

Tags: c#, winforms, static-classes

I use WinForms. In this app I can show a VIEW MODE and an EDIT MODE, both these modes will display a different panel (`Panel ViewPanel`, `Panel EditPanel`).

They both are only created ONCE, and they both contain other controls.. (`Label`s, `TextBox`es).

But the `ViewPanel` and `EditPane`l are not shown at the same time, so I need to be able to remove one and add the other so the user can see it.

In other classes I have functions & events that interact with, and may change, the mode from "Edit" to "View" so I would need to show or remove those panels.

I have created a panel (`WrapPanel`) to be their parent and so I display the `ViewPanel` or `EditPanel` by adding it to the `ControlCollection` of the `WrapPanel`. So removing the panel is easy, if I write:

```
WrapPanel.Controls.Clear();
```

It will easily remove whichever panel is showing, but in order to add the desired panel (`ViewPanel` or `EditPanel`) to the wrap I need to reference it from other classes (that have events and functions that may need to change the display from "Edit" to "View").

So having these panels declared somewhere as 'static' seems to make it easy to reference these panels from any class.

[I read in some forums to avoid making static classes, not sure exactly why and I wonder if this pertains to static variables too.]

Is it best practice to just declare these variables as static variables in `Form1`?

('public partial class Form1' is the default opening class for all WinForms apps)

Or is it better practice to make another (non-static) class 
-for example:

```
public class VarClass
```

and declare the Vars there as:

```
public Static Panel ViewPanel;
public Static Panel EditPanel;
```

Or 3rd option to make a static class - for example:

```
public static class StaticVarClass
```

and declare variables there (also with 'public static' keyword)

What is the best practice for performance and/or what are pro's & con's of each?

Comment: You need to read up on what static actually means. These situations are not equivalent and may not even be what you intend.

Comment: If you're shooting for OOP code, best practice would be to not have anything `static` at all. **Especially** not mutable public static fields.

Comment: Also, instead of asking for pros & cons and general "what's the best practice", I'd suggest you take some real, working code from a project you're working on, and put it up for peer review on [codereview.se] - if you're abusing `static` and public fields, reviewers will tell you everything you ever dreamed to know about why that's a bad idea.

Comment: @Budapest - Are you using the word "Var" as a short form of "Variable"?

Comment: @MatsMug i added some notes for Clarification. Please let me know if this helps you to help me)
 I will check out that link to CodeReview, thanks.

Comment: @Enigmativity "Yes"

Comment: Anyone know who down voted my question? I spent an hour trying to write this)) I am doing this App for free to help children learn languages.    So i am not asking someone to do my homework for me. And admittedly, I do not know OOP and was not trying to base my code on it, yet i think my desire to write a better functioning and readable code should still be valid, even if i don't have 4 years to go to school to learn everything; I appreciate that most of the commenters did, but remember SO is used by many people trying to learn who didn't have full access to schools, so share the love please!

Comment: Votes are anonymous on Stack Exchange, so nobody can know who voted up or down - not even moderators. I'd say the type of open-ended question being asked here doesn't quite line up well with the type of questions that are *expected* and generally well-received on this site, which generally involve a [mcve]. I suppose you've read [ask] already?

Comment: Yes, i have read it, but i guess i obviously dont not fully understand the terms:( Kinda stinks that i ask a question and my points go down:( I was trying to be more active here, but of course i am still a begginner, just writing apps for free to help others. Not to make salary. I really appreciate that you have taken time to comment. It refreshing. Unfortunately i cant give +1 because my reputation points are dropping so fast (soon will be negative). Teaches me to ask SO for help!))
At least i can do good thing for the community and mark as answered, for ROMA who spent some time to help too)

Comment: @Budapest - You shouldn't use you question to air your concerns about the down-voting system on SO - you're likely to get more down-votes for doing so.

Comment: @Budapest - Also, your question is long and rambles a bit so it's hard to follow - that's probably lead to down-votes. The best questions are short, sharp and shiny. Also, your use of capitals on a lot of words that were just basic nouns is confusing (in particular the use of "Vars" instead of "variables"). Your question could have been better by you writing less and doing so in a more terse manner.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I am grateful for your explanation. I see that i wrote too much. Sorry about that. I thought i had added the donwvoting concern as a comment. And isnt that ok? At least it got an answer! As for the rambling my intention was to make it easy for a non-native speaker to follow.. but i see now that i could make it much smaller if i knew you were the one answering. I live in foreign countries and often there is need for over stating Objects and Nouns! (i didnt realize anyone would misunderstand Var as Variable, it makes sense now. Thanks for cleaning that up! Glad you are here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't create an object of a class, and this class contains some constants for using globally, you should create static class. If object of the class is not needed your choice should be a static class.

If your variables are related to some functionality only, you should create class with static variables. Sometimes you want to create objects of a class and share some info among these objects. For that case, the best would be to create non-static class with static shared variables.

Comment: thanks, I didnt completely understand the first paragraph, i am not sure what u mean 'make an object of a class' .. guess you are talking about OOP, which i am just getting into. I try to clarify.. I have a Form that can show a VIEW MODE and an EDIT MODE, both these modes will display a different panel. In other classes i have events that interact with and may change the Mode from Edit to View so i would need to show or remove those panels.

Comment: Removing is easy as i have created a "Wrap" (panel) so the ViewModePanel and EditModePanel can be added to the ControlCollection of the "Wrap". So removing just have to "Wrap.Controls.Clear()" but to add i need to say which Panel to add and need a way to reference that Panel in multiple Classes. 
I hope this clarifies my situation.
 I am not sure if referencing the Panel means i am creating an Object, because Yes a panel is an Object but i am not re-creating it each time i reference it.. i am just referencing it so it can be placed on the Wrap (so the user can see it)

Comment: i figured out what you meant! Yes I have one case where i dont declare and object of a Class as that is a Static Class. And i have another case (the one listed in this question) where i use variables related to some functionality and so your answer really helped! Perfect advice, thank you for that. I selected you as the answer.

Comment: Examples of static classes are `Console`, `Debug`.You don't need to create objects of this classes, you simply call static methods. `Object` is not static class and you can create object of this class (to manipulate your data, pass this objects as parameters, etc) and this class has static methods (i.e. `ReferenceEquals` to compare if two references point to the same object)